# Speeding up list.contains

Tags: .net, list, generics

We have a C# library class which inherirts from List but is slow because List.Contains is slow. We can't change the class to inherit from something else like Dictionary or HashSet because a lot of client code depends upon this class and it's too involved to change the interface. Is there an easy a way to speed this method up without changing it? Some of the lists are very big so we don't want two copies in memory. We don't want to override every method of List either.

```
public class UniqueList<T> : List<T>, IList<T>
{
    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        if (!this.Contains(item) && item != null)
        {
            base.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your class is very problematic. As soon as someone doesn't use it with the compile time type of UniqueList but with `List<T>` or `IList<T>` your `Add` method will not be used because of the `new`

Comment: You are right, and it may not have been intentional (I didn't write it) but as nobody has complained about that there can't be anyone wanting to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Inheriting from List is a very bad idea as you don't have control on how your class is used by client code

List.Contains is a **O(n)** operation. Dictionary.ContainsKey is a **O(1)**, so I think using a Dictionary is the best advice given, but if you really don't want to use it, another possibility is to keep the list sorted to obtain **O(log n)**

```
public void Add(T item)
{
    int index = BinarySearch(item);
    if (index < 0)
    {
        Insert(~index, item);
    }
}
```

If the element is already in the list, BinarySearch returns its index. 
If the element is not in the list, BinarySearch method returns a negative number that is a binary complement of an index of the first element that is greater that the element I passed to binary search method.

Using BinarySearch might not be possible in your scenario, as it depends on what T can be:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx

*This method uses the default comparer Comparer.Default for type T to determine the order of list elements. The Comparer.Default property checks whether type T implements the IComparable generic interface and uses that implementation, if available. If not, Comparer.Default checks whether type T implements the IComparable interface. If type T does not implement either interface, Comparer.Default throws an InvalidOperationException.*

Comment: Good idea. The problem is I think it would change the behaviour of my "list" so that the items are returned in a different order to what they were added. I really need list-like behaviour so my class behaves the same but differs in its implementation only.

Answer (score 2):

In short No.

Because you're inheriting from `List<>` you're essentially screwed, because even if you do shadow the Contains method you you can't stop client code from passing a `UniqueList` to a method that accepts a `List<>`, this will hide your new Contains, and use the existing one.

You need to fix this the hard way, remove the inheritance on `List<>`, implement your own Contains, re-implement any methods you need from list (internally you can use a `private List<>` for storage, and simply delegate to that where necessary), and fix all the code that this change breaks.

While you're breaking things, you could have a look at the C5 collection classes, which promote developing against interfaces, helping you not hit this problem (I know, more closing of the barn door after the horse has bolted)

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but you're not going to get the answer you want (there really is no way to program around this, you could try something like [Castle Interceptors](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Interceptors.ashx), but I don't think they'll work in this instance . . . but then I can't be sure they won't)

Again, apologies for not being able to actually help.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a class level private Dictionary and check in the dictionary first if its not found in the dictionary then go to the list and check , its a optimization only its not th pure solution and also cost you to have additional memory

Comment: Problem is as I said some of the lists may be very long and the difference in memory could be appreciable

Comment: i am also interested to know the other possible approach